# Is there a way to make `fill-paragraph` stop at the end of a sentence?

Tags: emacs

It is sometimes desirable to start each sentence in a paragraph on a separate line.  For instance, this makes it easier to diff large text documents, because a change in one sentence will not affect the entire paragraph.  Some markup systems (e.g. *roff) also require each sentence to start on a new line.

Is there a way, e.g. by judicious redefinition of `paragraph-separate` and `paragraph-start`, to make `fill-paragraph` stop between sentences?

(note: I use Emacs 23.3.1)

---

Update: sample mdoc (*roff) markup:

```
The
.Nm
utility makes a series of passes with increasing block sizes.
In each pass, it either reads or writes (or both) a number of
non-consecutive blocks at increasing offsets relative to the ideal
alignment, which is assumed to be multiples of the block size.
The results are presented in terms of time elapsed, transactions per
second and kB per second.
```

This is a single paragraph with three sentences, each of which starts on a separate line even though there is room for the first word(s) on the previous line.  Currently, `fill-paragraph` will transform this into

```
The
.Nm
utility makes a series of passes with increasing block sizes.  In each
pass, it either reads or writes (or both) a number of non-consecutive
blocks at increasing offsets relative to the ideal alignment, which is
assumed to be multiples of the block size.  The results are presented
in terms of time elapsed, transactions per second and kB per second.
```

which is what I want to avoid.

---

Update: in re sentences and paragraphs

I see that my question is a bit unclear, because I used the term "paragraph" to refer both to what Emacs calls a paragraph and to what ends up as a continuous block of text in the output of whatever processor I use (groff, latex etc.).  To clarify,

- I need to keep the sentences together without any blank lines between them; groff doesn't like blank lines, while latex sees them as paragraph separators.
- I need `fill-paragraph` to operate on individual sentences, i.e. I want to redefine a paragraph as something that starts after either a blank line or the end of the previous paragraph, and ends with a period followed by either a newline character or at least two whitespace characters.
- I would love to have `fill-paragraph` break a block of text apart into individual sentences, but I don't think it can be done easily.

For instance, if I type the following:

```
The
.Nm
utility makes a series of passes with increasing block sizes.
In each pass, it either reads or writes (or both) a number of non-consecutive blocks at increasing offsets relative to the ideal alignment, which is assumed to be multiples of the block size.
The results are presented in terms of time elapsed, transactions per second and kB per second.
```

then move the point to the line that starts with "In each pass" and press `M-q`, I should get the following:

```
The
.Nm
utility makes a series of passes with increasing block sizes.
In each pass, it either reads or writes (or both) a number of
non-consecutive blocks at increasing offsets relative to the ideal
alignment, which is assumed to be multiples of the block size.
The results are presented in terms of time elapsed, transactions per second and kB per second.
```

Note that the last sentence is untouched.

Answer (score 1):

How about telling `paragraph-start` to look for any line that starts with a capital letter:

```
"\f\\|[     ]*$\\|^[A-Z]"
```

Note that the new part is `\\^[A-Z]`

That should work for most cases, you'd only have to watch for the rare cases where you have a capital mid-sentence, and that sentence happens to be long enough to break just before that mid-sentence word.

EDIT: you probably want to account for indentation too:

```
"\f\\|[     ]*$\\|^[    ]*[A-Z]"
```

The space between the square brackets contains a space and a tab.

EDIT: you need to turn off `case-fold-search` for this to work, otherwise capitals and lower case letters are not distinguished in the match!

EDIT: if you want to turn off case-fold-search for just this function, bind the following to `M-q` (which you can do locally or globally, as you see fit).

```
(defun my-fill-paragraph ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (fill-paragraph)))
```

Comment: Hmm, if Emacs's regexp syntax supports zero-width variable-length look-behind assertions, it should be possible to construct a regexp that corresponds to the Perl re `/\.(?:\n|\s{2,})\K\S/s`, which matches the first non-whitespace character after a period followed by a newline character or at least two whitespace characters.

Comment: You've lost me. When does the regexp I posted fail? I'm assuming you manually hit return after each sentence as you enter them, so that Emacs doesn't have to split the paragraphs for you, it just needs to respect sentence boundaries when filling.

Comment: I don't think Emacs supports assertions, either.

Comment: Capital letters do not necessarily indicate the start of a new sequence.  For instance, in your first comment, you capitalized a word in the middle of the third sentence.

Comment: True, but as I mentioned above, this only matters when there is a capital mid-sentence, and it falls exactly on a linebreak. And even then, if it falls exactly on a line break, the line will still break where you want it to. The edge case seems pretty rare relative to the effort of building a new fill function that covers every possible case ;)

Comment: This is changing paragraph motion and the definition of a paragraph, not just fill-paragraph.  The OP hasn't said if this is what he wants.

Comment: The OP said he wants fill-paragraph not to join consecutive sentences onto the same line, as is required by some mark-up formats (and is useful for revision control generally). He has stated no preference about paragraph motion, so I assume it's not important.

Comment: I don't mind either way (regarding paragraph motion).

I think this is as close as we're going to get to what I wanted, so I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Oops, un-accepted.  There is something wrong with this solution: `fill-paragraph` now correctly breaks long lines without touching the next sentence, but it never joins short lines together; I suspect that the regexp is applied in a case-insensitive manner, so it considers _any_ new line a new paragraph.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to set it globally, or even locally - I'd have to wrap `fill-paragraph` in a function that sets it to nil and then restores the value, unless you can think of something simpler.

Comment: The corner cases remain unsolved.  Modifying `fill-paragarph-function` works more broadly.  @Tyler, I was confused because he says "start each sentence in a paragraph", which I took to mean he wished to keep the concepts of a sentence and a paragraph distinct, but changing how paragraphs are defined does not accomplish that.  I'll let OP clarify what he actually wants.

Comment: This also effectively turns `fill-paragraph` into `fill-sentence`.  If we started out wanting this, I think the situation would be much easier.  :)

Comment: @Tyler How can I run `"\f\\|[     ]*$\\|^[A-Z]"` could we make a keybinding for it instead of manually entering it?

Answer (score 1):

Does this DTRT?

```
(defun separate-sentences (&optional beg end)
  "ensure each sentence ends with a new line.
When no region specified, use current paragraph."
  (interactive (when (use-region-p)
                   (list (region-beginning) (region-end))))
  (unless (and beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (forward-paragraph -1)
      (setq beg (point))
      (forward-paragraph 1)
      (setq end (point))))
  (setq end (if (markerp end)
                end
              (set-marker (make-marker) end)))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (while (re-search-forward (sentence-end) end t)
      (unless (or (looking-at-p "[ \t]*$")
                  (looking-back "^[ \t]*"))
        (insert "\n")))))

(defun fill-paragraph-sentence-groups (justify)
  "Groups of sentences filled together.  A sentence ending with newline marks end of group."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region (progn (forward-paragraph -1) (point))
                        (progn (forward-paragraph 1) (point)))
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (skip-chars-forward " \t\n")
      (while (not (or (looking-at-p paragraph-separate)
                      (eobp)))
        (fill-region (point)
                     (progn
                       (loop do (forward-sentence 1)
                             until (looking-at "[ \t]*$"))
                       (point))
                     justify)
        (unless (looking-back "^[ \t]*")
          (forward-line 1)))
      t)))

(defun fill-paragraph-sentence-individual (justify)
  "Each sentence in paragraph is put on new line."
  (save-excursion
    (separate-sentences)
    (fill-paragraph-sentence-groups justify)))

;; deployment option 1: add to major-mode hook

(add-hook 'text-mode-hook (lambda ()
                            (set (make-local-variable fill-paragraph-function) 'fill-paragraph-sentence-individual)))

;; deployment option 2: call my-fill-paragraph any where

(defun my-fill-paragraph (arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((fill-paragraph-function 'fill-paragraph-sentence-individual))
    (fill-paragraph arg)))
```

Two paragraph filling functions are presented above.  One grouping sentences that don't end on new line together.  Another breaking every sentence into a new line.

I only show how to deploy the individual one because that's what the OP wants.  Follow the model to deploy the groups version if you wish.

Comment: The question was not how to separate a paragraph into sentences, but how to prevent `fill-paragraph` from rejoining them.

Comment: The question isn't very clear.  Can you add some examples of what you want?  Do you also want to keep the current paragraph movement behavior?

Comment: I really _do_ mean "each sentence".  What makes you think I don't?

Comment: You can have it both ways.  Choose `fill-paragraph-sentence-groups` or `fill-paragraph-sentence-individual`.  IMO the groups version is more powerful because there is a way to stop sentence breaking builtin.

Comment: This solution does not add newline after `.` if there is one in the middle of two seperate sentences

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fill-region` which, unsurprisingly, only fills the current region.  Based on that you could define a `fill-sentence` function.  I guess a simplistic way to detect such sentences is to say:

- If the line ends with a `.`, `?`, or `!`, it's an end-of-sentence line.
- A line starts a sentence if its predecessor line is either empty or an end-of-sentence line.

It's rather tricky to get it to work correctly in all cases, though.

Comment: I was hoping for a combination of parameters that would make `fill-paragraph` DTRT.